# How to build a .net search engine without using many endpoints?

Tags: .net, sql-server, search

I am building a search engine. I use angular, .net and database mssql. 
The question is how to bulid search engine or make search queries? 
I tried to do endpoints, but there are a lot of them and I don't think that's the way to go. 
Could someone guide me, indicate some article or a working solution?

Or is it possible to combine these endpoints?

```
Sample Endpoints:
[HttpGet("searched/{term}")]
[HttpGet("searched/{categoryId}")]
[HttpGet("searched/{localization}")]

[HttpGet("searched/{localization}/{term}")]
[HttpGet("searched/{categoryId}/{localization}")]
[HttpGet("searched/{categoryId}/{subCategoryId}")]


[HttpGet("searched/{categoryId}/{subCategoryId}/{localization}")]
[HttpGet("searched/{categoryId}/{subCategoryId}/{term}")]


[HttpGet("searched/{categoryId}/{subCategoryId}/{localization}/{term}")]
```

Comment: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this were me I would take a single parameter such as `keyword` and then figure out what is later on.

If you have collections for each of these things and want users to know what they are querying at the time you should be structuring your endpoints something like this -

```
{controller}\{collection}?{key}={value}
```

Where a user is entering a value as a query you should be receiving it as part of a query , meaning a key value pair after the ?
As an example, lets say I know that I want to get a list of hotels my enpoint might look something like `api\hotels`, but if i wanted to get a specific hotel i might do something like `'api\hotels?hotelName=TheRitz'`